# Is holding serialised data bad practice for a database table?

Tags: mysql, database, json

In my web application, I store the users profile information in an encoded JSON array, an example is below.

```
{"youtube":"username","skype":"username","facebook":"username","twitter":"username","googlep":"username","steam":"username","origin":"username"}
```

Is this bad practice?

Comment: Depends on what you plan on doing with that information?

Comment: It depends. In general, I would have separate columns, so you can enforce size limits and use the values in queries, but some systems do indeed hold serialised data blocks in a single column. Wordpress comes to mind, and it seems to work well there!

Comment: When I saw the title, I thought you ask if MySQL is a bad practice and I was about to say yes .) But back to your question: I think it violates fist normal form.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I simply display it on the user's profile page, I don't use it as any type of index.

Comment: Do you plan on doing a search on it? For example, find a user by their skype name, or prevent duplicate skype names from being registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As also Burhan Khalid said in his comment that depends on what are you want to achive. If you just store that data for displaying them later this is good. So you won't have the overhead to convert the data to JSON. By the way this technique is called [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

The problem with such a JSON field is that you cannot query it with SQL. So this data are in some kind lost. However if you don't need to be able to search that data you can simply store them and handle the data on the client side.

But if you need to access the data you should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database. So you will be able to query the data and you have to convert the result to a JSON string. This is pretty simple with the function [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Yes see: [Normalizaion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you have to store one value in one field. and not multiple.

You better go with a second table like:

```
user_id   |  system   | username
   1      |  youtube  | the name
 .............................
```

while `user_id` is a foreign key to  your user table. and you have a combined primary key (`user_id`, `system`)

**UPDATE**
In production the normal level of normalization is level 3. as realizing higher normalizations is quite difficult. And of course, for several reasons (i don't see yours here), it might me good to *not* normalize a table/model or parts of it.

Comment: Normalization depends on the use case. For fast reads, denormalization is preferred. In your case, the answer needs context because I am sure you made some assumptions as to the use case for the OP.

Comment: Almost. The relational model allows values to be arbitrarily complex. Values can even be tables. The relational issue is how the dbms treats those complex values. The dbms has to either return them unchanged, or provide functions that operate on the complex structure. Dates and timestamps represent complex values, but the dbms provides functions that operate on them, and return, for example, the year, or the week, or the day of the week.

Comment: ok thats a good point @MikeSherrill'Catcall'